# A word to mention a set of products sold together with a bundle price?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Is there a word to refer to a set of products sold together, with a specific price?

For example:

- Product A is sold 10 dollars
- Product B is sold 10 dollars

Product A and B are sold together for 18 dollars. How can we call the result of this product grouping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative to bundle, consider [package](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/package).

Comment: It's quite common to say, "This is a package deal", meaning you get a discount for buying all the related products. Or "This comes with the package," meaning this product is included at no extra charge if you buy the others. Etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can say the two products have been [bundled](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bundle) together. [Product bundling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_bundling) is a commonly used sales strategy.

> (Free Dictionary) vb. (Business / Commerce) (tr) to give away (a relatively cheap product) when selling an expensive one to attract business several free cassettes are often bundled with music centres
>   (Webster) n. a package offering related products or services at a single price

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll use package as this is travel related. I just realized Expedia mentions travel packages on their website. Thanks anyway for your time!

Comment: No worries! Yes, package makes more sense if you're talking about products offered by a travel company.

Comment: I think "bundling" is more commonly used as a verb, while the result is a "package". As in, "We bundled A and B together to make our Super Discount Package." Perhaps because "packaging" already is commonly used as a noun meaning the box or other container that the product is sold or shipped in. People do sometimes talk about the result of bundling being a "bundle", but it's not as common.

Comment: Maybe it's not so common. I definitely have seen it used as a noun for tech products. "Cost of Photoshop + Acrobat bundle = $200"