# What is a common English term for products sold and bought as a set?

Tags: expressions

In case the price is not considered, then what are the products called? (For example, toothpaste and a toothbrush; a cleasning cream, facial mask pack, and a skin nourishing cream) In South Korea, such products are usually called 'set.' Then, is it common or does it make sense if I call them 'set products (products sold and bought as a set)'? Or is there any other term widely used in English-speaking countries?

Comment: You are very fast. Let me show you how it works. If your question is related with a previous [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63935/a-word-to-mention-a-set-of-products-sold-together-with-a-bundle-price), you are required to post the link. Also, you need to specify why the previous answers don't answer your question. Otherwise, your question might be closed as "off-topic". Did you take time to read "help center"?

Comment: *Set* is a common term like *bathroom set, tool set, facial cleaning set* etc.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen **Combo** being used in America.

See example here: http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=combo

Answer (score 1):

Consider,

***package deal***

> *Fig.* a collection or group of related goods or services sold as a unit. *I got all these tools in a package deal for only $39.95*. *What about giving me all three shirts as a package deal?* [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/package+deal)

***bundle offer***

> Bundling
>
> The practice of joining related products together for the purpose of
>   selling them as a single unit. This is generally carried out when the
>   seller thinks that the characteristics of two or more products and
>   services are such that these products might appeal to many consumers
>   more as a package than as individual offerings e.g. local and long
>   distance services. Bundling arrangements usually feature a special
>   pricing arrangements which make it cheaper to buy the products and
>   services as a bundle than separately. Bundling is also often a way for
>   creating a larger market for relatively low value products by selling
>   them cheap (or giving them away free) with a higher value product e.g.
>   ******MED_REC_HERE*********giving away free floppy disks with the purchase of high-end computer software. The floppies might be an
>   incentive to buy that particular software, and quite possibly the
>   software price has a slight mark-up in it to cover the cost of the
>   floppies. [Investor Words](http://www.investorwords.com/620/bundling.html#ixzz3rgJaXIn1)